# React reusable form group checkboxes component need to pass an array object with its props

Tags: reactjs, components, formgroups, arrayobject, formik-material-ui

I am trying to create a reusable form group component that I can use anywhere in the app I have used material-ui and formik. This is the reusable form group component that I created

```
import { 
  Checkbox,
  FormControl, 
  FormControlLabel, 
  FormGroup, 
  FormLabel,
  FormHelperText } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useField, useFormikContext } from 'formik';

const CheckboxesGroup = ({
  name,
  label,
  legend,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
  const [field, meta] = useField(name);
  // const { morning_slot, afternoon_slot, evening_slot } = field;
  // const error = [morning_slot, afternoon_slot, evening_slot].filter((v) => v).length < 1;

  const handleChange = (evt) => {
    const { checked } = evt.target;
    setFieldValue(name, checked);
  };

  const configCheckbox = {
    ...field,
    onChange: handleChange
  };
  

  const configFormControl = {
        error:{error},
        component:"fieldset",
        sx:{ m: 3 },
        variant:"standard"
  };
  if (meta && meta.touched && meta.error) {
    configFormControl.error = true;
  } 

  return (   
      <FormControl {...configFormControl} >
        <FormLabel component="legend">Time-Slot</FormLabel>
        <FormGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox {...configCheckbox} />}
            label={label}
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormHelperText>Select altleast one Slot</FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
  );
}

export default CheckboxesGroup;
```

and i need help to pass this from the Form.js file

```
facility = [
  {id: 'morning_slot', name: 'morning_slot', label: 'Morning Slot [5AM-10PM]'},
  {id: 'afternoon_slot', name: 'afternoon_slot', label: 'Afternoon Slot [12PM-4PM]'},
  {id: 'evening_slot', name: 'evening_slot', label: 'Evening Slot [5PM-10PM'}
];
```

to that component and I don't know if there is a need for mapping or not.
can someone look into this and reply with the corrected code

Answer (score 0):

When you call the component from the `File.js` and pass the props like this:

```
<CheckboxesGroup prop_name=facility ><\CheckboxesGroup>
```

And get the your props in the CheckboxesGroup function:

```
const CheckboxesGroup = (props) => {
    ..... 
    const myfacility = props.prop_name;
    // myfacility should look like the facility props you passed from the `File.js`
}
```